# solc-js error: "before each" hook for "deploys a contract": SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: web3js, contract-development, solc, mocha, ganache-cli

The issue is probably here: `const { interface, bytecode } = require('../compile');`.

`interface` in the test file is `undefined`.

inbox/contracts/Inbox.sol:

```solidity
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

contract Inbox {
    string public message;

    constructor(string memory initialMessage) {
        message = initialMessage;
    }

    function setMessage(string memory newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

inbox/compile.js:

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8');

var input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'Inbox.sol' : {
            content: source
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': [ "abi", "evm.bytecode" ]
            }
        }
    }
};

module.exports = solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input));
```

inbox/test/Inbox.test.js:

```js
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
const { interface, bytecode } = require('../compile');

let accounts;
let inbox;
beforeEach(async () => {
    //get a list of all accounts

    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    //use one of those accounts to deploy the contract
    inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
        .deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: ['Hi there!'] })
        .send({from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000'});
});

describe('Inbox', () => {
    it('deploys a contract', () => {
        console.log(inbox);
    })
})
```

when running `npm run test` it throws:

```
  Inbox
    1) "before each" hook for "deploys a contract"


  0 passing (366ms)
  1 failing

  1) "before each" hook for "deploys a contract":
     SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
      at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\Inbox.test.js:15:46)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Comment: Your problem is at `JSON.parse(interface)`. Check what the value of the `interface` variable is. Since it is not a string which represents a JSON object, you cannot pass it to `JSON.parse`.

Comment: it's `undefined` but i don't get why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved this way:

```js
const compile = require('../compile');
const interface = JSON.parse(compile).contracts["Inbox.sol"].Inbox.abi;
const bytecode = JSON.parse(compile).contracts["Inbox.sol"].Inbox.evm.bytecode.object;
```

Answer (score 1):

I renamed interface variable "abi" and removed the Parse from `beforeEach` in the test file because that's being done in the compiler.

**Compile.JS file**

```
// build path from compiler to solidity file
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

//for unix and windows
//take you from root dir to this inbox folder and both files
const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'inbox.sol');

// read contents of file with encoding
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf-8');

var input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'inbox.sol' : {
            content: source
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': [ '*' ]
            }
        }
    }
};


// parses solidity to English and strings 
var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

var outputContracts = output.contracts['inbox.sol']['Inbox']

// exports ABI interface
module.exports.abi = outputContracts.abi;

// exports bytecode from smart contract
module.exports.bytecode = outputContracts.evm.bytecode.object;
```

**inbox.test.js**

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
// constructor
const Web3 = require('web3');
// new instance and to connect it to ganache
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

const {abi, bytecode} = require('../compile');


// set global variables
let accounts;
let inbox;

beforeEach(async () =>  {
    // get list of all accounts
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()

    // use account to deploy contract
    inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract((abi))
        .deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: ['Hi there!']})
        .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000'});

});

describe('Inbox', () => {
    it('deploys a contract', () => {
        console.log(inbox)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't parse your abi, and the bytecode is inside env.bytecode.object

```
const { abi, evm } = require('./compile');

const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
     .deploy({ data: evm.bytecode.object, arguments: ["Hi!"] })
     .send({ gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0] });
```

Answer (score 0):

In compile.js

```
const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

const interface = output.contracts['inbox.sol'].Inbox.abi;
const bytecode = output.contracts['inbox.sol'].Inbox.evm.bytecode.object;

module.exports = {
    interface,
    bytecode,
};
```

In test.js

```
 inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(interface)
    .deploy({data: bytecode, arguments: ['Hi there !']})
    .send({from: accounts[0],gas:'1000000'});
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check your 'compile.js' file should be exporting contract object something like.

example:
module.exports = solc.compile(source,1).contracts[':Inbox'];

Comment: That will not work for solc 0.7. It has a new syntax.